# Applying constraints to the type arguments of parameterized types

Tags: regex, maven, jaxb

I'm trying to enforce a @Pattern constraint on List attributes of my JAXB classes.

Similar to this:

```
public List <@Pattern(regex="test") String> names;
```

How can I archive via bindings file:

```
  <annox:annotate target = "field"> .........(regexp ="test")</annox:annotate>
```

I have tried using the @EachPattern annotation via bindings file:

```
<annox:annotate target = "field"> @cz.jirutka.validator.collection.constraints.EachPattern(regexp ="test")</annox:annotate>
```

Which always results in a Nullpointer exception while testing:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(SystemUtils.java:1371)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.isAssignable(ClassUtils.java:589)
at cz.jirutka.validator.collection.internal.AnnotationUtils.createAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:133)
at cz.jirutka.validator.collection.CommonEachValidator.createConstraintAndCopyAttributes(CommonEachValidator.java:291)
at cz.jirutka.validator.collection.CommonEachValidator.initialize(CommonEachValidator.java:92)

Test:

```
  @Test
  public void testValidPattern()
  {

    Customer customer  = new Customer();

    customer.names = new ArrayList<>();
    customer.names.add("test");
    customer.names.add("test");
    List<String> namesList = customer.getNames();

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    CommonEachValidator validator = new CommonEachValidator();
    validator.setValidatorFactory(factory);
    Annotation eachAnnotation = new EachPattern()
    {

      @Override
      public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType()
      {
        return EachPattern.class;
      }

      @Override
      public String regexp()
      {
        return "test";
      }

      @Override
      public Pattern.Flag[] flags()
      {
        return new Pattern.Flag[0];
      }

      @Override
      public String message()
      {
        return "Valid Pattern";
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?>[] groups()
      {
        return new Class[0];
      }

      @Override
      public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload()
      {
        return new Class[0];
      }
    };
    validator.initialize(eachAnnotation);
    assertTrue(validator.isValid(namesList, null), "Valid pattern should pass");


  }
```

Comment: Which commons-lang3 version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by updating commons-lang version

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>cz.jirutka.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>validator-collection</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Since you override the commons-lang3 version by providing direct dependency, you don't need to exclude it from `cz.jirutka.validator:validator-collection`